# Prevent form resubmit in Zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

An action within a controller generates the next id from the database and displays it on screen as reference. How can I prevent the action being called again if the user clicks refresh.

Answer (score 3):

The post-redirect-get pattern with Zend Framework would generally involve leaving the action of the form empty (so it posts to itself) and then redirecting when you don't want to display the form again (so upon success).

```
public function newAction() {
    $form = new Form_Foo();
    if($this->_request->isPost()) {
        if($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()) {
            //save or whatever
            return $this->_redirect('path/to/success');
        }
        // else fall through
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Comment: If the form data is valid then I do some processing on it. How can I pass the output of the processing to the view page that the user has been redirected to?

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($this->isPost()) {
   // Check validation
   if ($error) {
       $dataToMove = array();
       // $dataToMove is array that you want to pass with redirect
       // It can be an array of errors or form data that user has entered

       // Use FlashMessenger helper to pass data to redirection via Zend_Session
       $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->addMessage($dataToMove);

       // And redirect page to form url
       $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector')->goToUrl('/form/url/');
}

// If not posted, get data from FlashMessenger
$data = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->getMessages();

// And assign to view or make that you want
$this->view->formData = $data;
```

Comment: I like this answer, as it allows you to redirect and keep success/error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is older post people still come here for answers, so let me help a bit more.

Redirecting form is great and useful but we are still not preventing peple from clicking back button and resubmitting that way.

The solution is to either show the form as popup and make it disapear when done (easily done with jquery) or generate unique id for each transaction and checking if id was previously used.
See article: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/stoprefresh.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing a 302 redirect

```
header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
header('Location: displayId.php?id=5');
die();
```

Assuming you have these pages

- form.php
- processForm.php
- displayId.php

**Form.php** only displays form and sends data via POST to **processForm.php**.
Within **processForm.php** you can parse data and issue the redirect to **displayId.php** with id you want to display in GET parameter.

This way when user refreshes the page (displayId.php) the form data is not processed again.

Comment: I'm more interested in how it can be done within Zend Framework.

Comment: Actually you should be using 303 for this, not 302.

Comment: Good point, thank you for pointing it out, another thing learned.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're trying to do this in Zend Framework but I'm just saying I'm after the same functionality. Just moved everything to ZF and I'm quite disappointed to see that this functionality isn't built in.

I used to have every form submit to process.php which processed all GET, POST requests and then saved the results (like error and success messages) and redirected you to the new place.

If $_SESSION['post_data'] was set, I would $_POST = $_SESSION['post_data']; and then remove it from the session.

This worked great but now I'm gonna need the same in ZF :D As I say... a little disappointed as I don't believe ANYONE wants a dialog to appear asking about resubmitting data.. what the hell does that mean to your enduser? nothing!